# Persisting message in Storage Extension

Tags: 2013, storage-extensions

OK, so here is the thing...
I have been hitting my head for a week now. I have a Storage Extension in 2013 which fails at some point. I want to persist its message to Publish Popup. In Storage Extension I throw an exception, which is then picked up by `com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction()`. 
But if I open this method, I see that it completely ignores my message and just thows new `ProcessingException` with message: "Unable to commit transactions" which is then shown in UI.
[image]

So here is my question: **Are all storage exceptions swallowed? Can I in any form persist message from Storage Extension to UI, because if I take a look at the code, it doesn't to be the case. Does anyone know how is this handled in other extensions, for example, SI4T?**

here is my stack trace from deployer log:

```
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-1788570-66560
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction(AbstractStorageStep.java:34) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.execute(CommitPhase.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-1788570-66560 because of REASONS.
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:358) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction(AbstractStorageStep.java:32) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.amynamespace.exception.OperationFailedException: REASONS.
        at com.tridion.storage.CmsApiDaoFactory.commitTransaction(CmsApiDaoFactory.java:100) ~[trid-netstorage-storage-extension.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:354) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question, no at this moment in version 9.5 and earlier it is not possible to persist message to publish UI from storage extension.